# Auto restart tomcat when OutOfMemoryError occurs

Tags: java, tomcat

When OutOfMemoryError occurs, I need to auto restart tomcat in server side. The easiest way to do this is using a JVM options: OnOutOfMemoryError="service tomcat restart".

Problem: Tomcat was run by tomcat user. The tomcat user don't have permissions to restart tomcat using service command, or run /etc/init.d/tomcat6 directly (some commands in this script can only be executed by root).

Besides, make tomcat user sudoer is not a good idea. Are there any better way to do this?

Comment: Find your memory leak would be a best option form me. You can find some useful articles here https://plumbr.eu/blog

Answer (score 5):

The solution is to fix the memory leak, not to auto restart to get around it.  That is not really a solution and is still going to bounce out all of your users and force them to log back in.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from fixing your OOM, use a Service Wrapper to (auto-re)start your JVM instance such as the [Tanuki Java Service Wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp)

Version 3.2.3 is under LGPL if I do remember correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If this is caused by a memory leak, you should fix that. However, sometimes this can happen when some type of high-usage uses lots of memory, and it is not so easy to impose a hard-limit. If so...

On your system, if Tomcat crashes, does something (like FireDaemon) restart it automatically? If so, instead of trying to restart, you can simply try exiting

```
  System.exit(1);
```

That will end Tomcat.  However, sometimes, even this may not work when you're out of memory.

Therefore, another way to address this is to have a mechanism that warns you when you cross some percentage of memory usage (say 85%). There are free Tomcat monitoring solutions that can help with this; or, you could try to roll your own... something simple.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, if you have no control over the code of the application you are using, no matter what the reason, is to run it inside a container.

I have a tomcat 9 and a GeoServer application running inside a docker container. Sometimes, requests crash my application and the error in the log is OutOfMemory.
I adjusted my JVM parameters to use as much memory as possible, but this error still occurs sometimes. So, to prevent this error from keeping my service locked, I using the OnOutOfMemoryError parameter to kill the tomcat. Since the container is only maintained when the main process is running, and in this case, that process is the tomcat, so when we kill it, the container is stopped.

Tomcat environment to set the JVM parameters.

```
CATALINA_OPTS="-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=\"kill -9 %p\"
-Djava.awt.headless=true \
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -server \
-Xms1024m -Xmx3072m -Xss1024k -XX:NewSize=768m \
-XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=500"
```

This approach forces the container out because the tomcat is dropped.

You can automatically restart failed containers by specifying a restart policy when starting the container. To do this, you must use **--restart=always** or another possible policy, as defined in [the docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/).

```
docker run -d --name testing_restarts --restart always you_docker_image_with_tomcat:<version>
```