# Geoserver - automatically detect its stop and restart

Tags: restart, geoserver

I use Geoserver on Windows server and it sometimes stops for some reason. How can I automatically detect its stop and restart?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend https://mmonit.com/monit/ for this to monitor tomcat and restart it if needed. It is also best to make [tomcat fail on OOM errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22150488/auto-restart-tomcat-when-outofmemoryerror-occurs) rather than trying to limp on.